# Php/pdo/mysql multiple DB calls best practise

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When reviewing my scripts so far, I realized I used two different ways for retrieving/updating data : multiple calls within a `try/catch` or multiple `try/catch` with one call for each.

Results look fine with my test data when using either method but I'd like to be fixed on the best practise used in a production environment as test data isn't real life. I am for instance wondering if there is any chance not getting the correct exception in a multiple calls within a `try/catch`.

On some scripts I have like 30 db calls with 30 `open/close db` using `try/catch`, on others I have like 30 db calls with 6 `open/close db` using `try/catch`.

Thanks.

Example method 1

```
try {
    $connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$serveur;dbname=$db;charset=$charset", $login, $pwd);
    $connexion -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    select table1 / execute / process
    join table1 & table2 / execute / process
    update table3 / execute / process
    ...
    $connexion = null; // close

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connexion failed:".$e -> getMessage();
    }
```

Example method 2

```
try {
    $connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$serveur;dbname=$db;charset=$charset", $login, $pwd);
    $connexion -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    select table1 / execute / process

    $connexion = null; // close

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connexion failed:".$e -> getMessage();
    }

try {
    $connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$serveur;dbname=$db;charset=$charset", $login, $pwd);
    $connexion -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    join table1 & table2 / execute / process

    $connexion = null; // close

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connexion failed:".$e -> getMessage();
    }

try {
    $connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$serveur;dbname=$db;charset=$charset", $login, $pwd);
    $connexion -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    update table3 / execute / process

    $connexion = null; // close

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connexion failed:".$e -> getMessage();
    }
```

**Update**

I knew I was doing something wrong (I'm learning PHP on my own). On another hand, I can now appreciate the value of solutions made by Shudhansh Shekhar and e4c5.

So I built a DBaccess class and I can see all the advantages. One include at the top of the script with a new instance and you're almost done. I tested on one script and it's working like a charm.

Can you please validate my code before I reengineer all my scripts ? I'm not sure if `$this->connexion = null;` is at the correct location to close db.

Thanks again for your help.

**DBaccess.class.php**

```
<?php
class DBaccess{
    private $serveur = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "qh61test";
    private $charset = "utf8";
    private $login = "root";
    private $pwd = "";

    private $connexion;   // dbh name
    private $erreur;
    private $requete;     // sql stmt

    public function __construct(){
        $this->connexion = null; // <-----------  NOT SURE ?
        try{
            $this->connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->serveur . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name. ";charset=". $this->charset, $this->login, $this->pwd);
            $this->connexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Connexion foirée :".$e -> getMessage();
            // $this->erreur = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function sql($sql){
        $this->requete = $this->connexion->prepare($sql);
    }
    public function execute(){
        return $this->requete->execute();
    }
    public function resultAll(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->requete->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } 
}
?>
```

**script.php**

```
        <?php 
        session_start();
        include 'DBaccess.class.php';
        $db = new DBaccess();
        ...
        if (isset($_POST['periode'])) { 

            // sales within a period
            if (!empty($_POST['datebeg']) && !empty($_POST['dateend'])) {

               // datepicker dates
               $datebeg = preg_replace("([^0-9/])", "", $_POST['datebeg']);
               $dateend = preg_replace("([^0-9/])", "", $_POST['dateend']);

            $search_row = "SELECT COUNT(cmdID) as nbcmd FROM Commande2 WHERE date_cmd BETWEEN '$datebeg' AND '$dateend'"
            );

                $db->sql("$search_row"); 
                $db->execute();
                $resultat = $db->resultAll();   

            foreach($resultat as $row)
            {
           if ($row['nbcmd'] == 0) {            
                 $no_rows = "No sales for that period";
                 $all = '<div>
                    <button class="btn  btn-mini btn-primary bold" type="submit" name="all">All saless</button></div>';
                    }
            }
         }
        }

    // retrieve all sales or sales within period
    if (empty($errors) && empty($no_rows) || isset($_POST['all'])) {

    $search_tot = array(
        "select" => "SELECT COUNT(cmdID) as nbcmd, SUM(`articles_cmd`) as total_articles, SUM(`total_cmd_nofp`) as somme, AVG(`total_cmd_nofp`) as moyenne, MIN(`total_cmd_nofp`) as mini, MAX(`total_cmd_nofp`) as maxi, MIN(`date_cmd`) as date_mini, MAX(`date_cmd`) as date_maxi FROM Commande2",
        "where" => " WHERE ",
        "periode" => "date_cmd BETWEEN '$datedeb' AND '$datefin'"
    );

        if (empty($datebeg) && empty($dateend)) {
           unset($search_tot["where"],$search_tot["periode"]);
        }
    }
    $search_tot = implode(' ', $search_tot);

        // fetch all matching rows
        $db->sql("$search_tot"); 
        $db->execute();
        $resultat = $db->resultAll();   

        foreach($resultat as $row)
        {
            $date1 = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['date_mini']));
            $date1 = str_replace('-', '/', $date1);
            $date2 = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['date_maxi']));
            $date2 = str_replace('-', '/', $date2);

            $orders= '<div style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">Sales for '.$date1.' to '.$date2.'/div>';
             ...
        }
...
```

Comment: Why not prefer to create a DB handler class so that ....... you code with calm with just one line code $this->db.

Comment: If these queries will carry on to grow, i'm worried you will burn your database

Comment: mysql's connection protocol isn't particularly "heavy", but it's still a waste of resources to connect/execute/disconnect every time. it also makes it impossible to do things like multi-query transactions, keep server-side variables, etc... because all of those are destroyed/cleaned-up every time you disconnect.

Comment: @Marc B - Totally agree, it has been a pain declaring variables again and again when closing connections after each call. thanks.

Comment: @Shudhansh Shekhar - I was also anxious my cpu melt away :) see update. thanks.

Comment: That's like a PHP geek. Today you stepped toward professional scripting. Carry on. :))

Comment: and one more thing ...  " $this->connexion = null " will not affect the rest of code and is at right place. After all you're declaring it in try statement.

Comment: about the only time you should/NEED to have mutiple connections is if you need to access the db server with different credentials (e.g. a read/write connection, and a read-only), or if you're doing a query that would cause "commands out of sync" in the client, and have to run multiple queries in parallel.

Comment: This seems ok at a glance but in your present form (after the edit) this question is a candidate for closure. The nature of the question has changed to a code review question which is actually off topic for stack overflow.

Comment: Thank you all, I like your advices and this way of programming PHP. I close the question, accept e4c5 response as an answer and special thanks to  Shudhansh Shekhar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On some scripts I have like 30 db calls with 30 open/close db using
>   try/catch

But why? You only need to open a connection once. That connection can be used for an number of queries and will be good for eight whole hours!

Simply delete all but one of these pairs.

```
$connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$serveur;dbname=$db;charset=$charset",    $login, $pwd);
$connexion -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Better still move it out to another file that you include in every page that needs to connect to the db. That way if your database settings change you only need to change one file.

> on others I have like 30 db calls with 6 open/close db using
>   try/catch.

If you are talking of 30 queries, that's most unusual for a single webpage. This is something that you might want to reconsider. It might be possible to rewrite your code to achieve the same objetive in a fewer number of queries.

Comment: how can I since he has only posted things like `select table1 / execute / process
    join table1 & table2 / execute / process
    update table3 / execute / process` @ShudhanshShekhar

Comment: Atleast show him how to reuse connection. I think that may be enough.

Comment: @e4c5 - Thanks for your reply. In fact I gave the worst script example I wrote in the first days (it has been splitted since). The average is more 3/4 db calls per script. It was more a general example to get the right direction. see update. thanks.